# Scan for wifi networks using C

Tags: c++, c, unix, wifi

I'm attempting to create a C program that will scan for wifi networks. I'm not sure what the best ways to this are.

The one plausible idea I have so far is the following
Use C to run the bash code for wifi scanning, then pipe the results back
Cons: might require use of sudo

At this point I'm hoping someone is more familiar with this type of problem and can offer a better/more elegant solution.

*I'm using Mac OSX, but I'll take a solution for any common unix system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the Apple [CoreWLAN Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/CoreWLANFrameworkRef/_index.html). It is written for Objective-C (which is a superset of C) but I believe you can figure out a way to use it from within a C++ or a C program.
Hope this helps.